# Float ops found in quantized TensorFlow MobileNet model

Tags: tensorflow, quantization

[image: loat ops found in quantized TensorFlow MobileNet model]

As you can see in the screenshot of a quantized MobileNet model implemented in TensorFlow, there are still some float operations. The quantization is done in TensorFlow via the graph_transform tools.

The red ellipse in the image has its description in the right-hand-size text box. The "depthwise" is a "DepthwiseConv2dNative" operation that expects "DT_FLOAT" inputs.

Despite the lower Relu6 performs an 8-bit quantized operation, the result has to go through "(Relu6)" which is a "Dequantize" op, in order to produce "DT_FLOAT" inputs for the depthwise convolution.

Why is depthwise conv operations left out by TF graph_transform tools? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a quantized version of depthwise conv in standard TensorFlow, so it falls back to the float implementation with conversions before and after. For a full eight-bit implementation of MobileNet, you'll need to look at TensorFlow Lite, which you can learn more about here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/